# histogram with one column per each value in R

Tags: r, histogram

I am trying to plot simple histogram in R. I have an integer vector and I want to draw a histogram with one column per each value.

```
test_data = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4)
hist(test_data)
```

But I get this

[image]

Please tell me whether it is possible to get the same result as I have in Python?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
test_data = [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4]
plt.hist(test_data)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could us the barplot and table functions

```
barplot(table(test_data))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `nclass` or `breaks` argument to adjust the number of bins.

```
test_data = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4)
hist(test_data,breaks=5)
hist(test_data,nclass=5)
```

[image]

In fact it is the same thing for python. The argument is `bins`. The default value is 10 (according to [this page](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html))

So if you modify it, we will get a different plot

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
test_data = [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4]
plt.hist(test_data,bins=4)
plt.show()
```

you get

[image]